# logging out with/without confirmation - single site, multisite

Tags: multisite, logout

I have two wordpress installations: a single one and a multisite with subdirectories. On both my users can logout with the url:

```
[URL to]/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=%2Fmydir%2F&_wpnonce=[some_code]
```

This works on the single site without confirmation, but on the site within the multisite it doesn't. Here the user needs to confirm the logout.

How can I bypass the confirmation?

Thank you.

Comment: Have found the best solution and explanation : https://www.scratchcode.io/how-to-logout-without-confirmation-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

Output the logout link with `wc_logout_url()` and it will be nonced and have no confirmation. The confirmation is a security measure.

You could also try adding the following to your functions.php or a plugin:

```
// Logout without confirmation.
function wpse_bypass_logout_confirmation() {
    global $wp;

    if ( isset( $wp->query_vars['customer-logout'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( str_replace( '&', '&', wp_logout_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) ) );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_bypass_logout_confirmation' );
```

Comment: I'm not using WooCommerce. I'm using on both pages php code `echo '<a href="'.wp_logout_url($referer).'">Logout</a>';` This generates on both pages this url. But on multisite installation it requires a confirmation.

Comment: That’s why I provided the add_action option

Comment: Now I know the cause, I will communicate the solution later. It is not a multisite problem. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the urls from my Wordpress installations is

```
/wpone/   # Single site installation
/wptwo/   # Multisite installation with subdirectories
/wptwo/site1/
/wptwo/site2/
```

and so on. Furthermore, I have a directory

```
/site1/
```

on which I call via .htaccess the content of

```
/wptwo/site1/
```

When a user logs in, Wordpress set 3 cookies: `wordpress_test_cookie`, `wordpress_logged_in` and `wordpress_sec`. `wordpress_test_cookie` and `wordpress_logged_in` are valid only for `/wptwo/site1/` and not for `/site1/`. This is checked during the generation of wpnonce. When I call `/site1/logout/`, it is not the same as `/wptwo/site1/logout/`. Logout via `/wptwo/site1/logout/` works without confirmation.